# Docker Windows new container options

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

When I create a new container in docker windows, there  are optional settings to give it a name, and under 'Volumes' there is 'Host Path' and 'Container Path'. Are these for somehow connecting local host with the container? How does it work?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volumes in the new Docker Desktop correspond to Docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). You can also use volumes with the Docker CLI's `-v` flag when you run a container. This mounts a path from your host machine's filesystem (Windows) to your Docker container's filesystem.

For example, if you set Host Path: `C:\User\Username\Projects` and Container Path: `/home/projects`, the contents of your `Projects` directory on Windows would be "shared" (actually bind-mounted) to your Docker container. The corresponding Docker command would be: `docker run -v C:\Users\Username\Projects:/home/projects MP4`

See the [bind-mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) docs for more information.

Comment: I'm getting an error of invalid path. 
host path: Desktop\MP4
container path: MP4

Comment: @amnesic Try to provide an absolute path, like `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\MP4`.

Comment: So after I do that :\Users\Username\Desktop\MP4 directory is still empty? Whereas when I run ls on my docker container cli, there are a bunch of files showing.

Comment: I gave that path in my previous comment as an example. You should give a path that actually exists on your host filesystem. Also, you usually use bind-mounts to share files from your host to the container, not copy a directory off your container. I'd recommend choosing a directory you want to mount on your host machine and paste its absolute path into **Host Path**, then specify the absolute path to mount it to inside the container in **Container Path**.

Comment: Sorry for late followup. But what is container path going to be?

Comment: @amnesic The path you want to mount the directory to in your container, in the container's filesystem.

Comment: can I just leave it blank? I want to leave it in base directory.

Comment: It depends on your usecase and what type of container you're using. If you're working on some application, you could make a new directory to work in, set it to something like `/app`.